# Change payment failure notice that shows at the top of the checkout page in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the text that shows after a payment failure at the top of the checkout page. I am unsure how to edit the notice and which action, filter and hook I should use.

I want to use this in my custom plugin

```
$error_message = "there was a problem with gateway. please try again";
wc_add_notice( __('Payment error:', 'woothemes') . $error_message, 'error' );
return;
```

The gateway uses the above code to throw the error message. I found this in the woocommerce docs for custom gateway plugins.

Comment: Show more code please.

Comment: i just want to change the gateway notice